# startup and catlina batch file missing in tomcat 6

Tags: tomcat

actually i am trying to use tomcat 6 with Net beans 6.9 but when I am installing the tomcat 6
(binary distribution windows service installer) ,it installs successfully but when i am trying to start the service the service could not be started and even no error message is shown .when I looked in the bin folder neither Catalina nor the start up and shutdown.bat is present I have tried it a number of times but the same problem occurs again and again ...please reply soon
looking forward for your reply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting the CATALINA_HOME environment variable to your tomcat directory.
The newer tomcat version dont have startup.bat or catalina.bat, the have tomcat.exe which is used to start tomcat.